# Using Paypal PDT with other paypal buttons made, don't want to override success url on those?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have multiple other paypal buy it now buttons created and active on my account.

I have it set up so it has a "success url" and "cancel url" on each.

I am now trying to POST variables back to my website to use for my own purpose.

So I have a Buy it now button on my website that has an event name text field. I am looking for an easy way to use the PDT system so after payment, it will attach some POST variable (like the event name field) so I can use it to populate another form)

The problem that I am having is the PDT requirements say that I need to have auto-return ON, but then all my other buttons that I created are screwed up and return to that other URL and not the "Success URL" that I created in the button??

I know there is a simple solution.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "success url" and "cancel url" set up on all buttons, this will override whatever you specify in your Profile.
So you can just enable 'Auto Return' and start using with your new button without any worries, as all existing buttons will still return back to their proper return URL's.

Comment: Yep. The same logic applies to shipping amounts (if you tick that option in the shipping calculator), tax amounts and IPN (notify_url).